# Return Documents with Null Field in Multi Level Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using Multi Level Aggregation. We have Buckets of City and each Bucket has Buckets of Class.
For Few documents Class is Null and in such cases an empty bucket is returned for the City. Please refer to below response:

Sample Output:

```js
"aggregations":
{
  "CITY":{
    "buckets":[
      {
        "key":"CITY 1",
        "doc_count":2
        "CLASS":{
          "buckets":[
            {
              "key":"CLASS A",
              "top_tag_hits":{
                
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "key":"CITY 2",
        "doc_count":2
        "CLASS":{
          "buckets":[
            
              
            
          ]
        }
      },
    ]
      
    
  }
}
```

Here the key CITY 2 has an empty bucket of CLASS as all documents under key CITY 2 has the field CITY as null. But we are having a doc count.
How can we return documents under the bucket when terms field is null

Update:
Field Mapping for CLASS:

```
"CLASS":
        {
                    "type": "string",

                    "index_analyzer": "text_with_autocomplete_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "text_standard_analyzer",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "string",
                             "null_value" : "na",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "partial_matching": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index_analyzer": "text_with_partial_matching_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer": "text_standard_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Please refer to mapping to solve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`missing` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_missing_value_12) for the [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) in order to handle buckets with missing values. So in your case, you'd do it like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "CITY": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city_field"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "CLASS": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "class_field",
            "missing": "NO_CLASS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this setup, all documents that don't have a `class_field` field (or a null value) will land in the `NO_CLASS` bucket.

PS: Note that this only works since ES 2.0 and not in prior releases.

Comment: Currently we are using ES 1.4. How can we achieve this in lower versions of ES

Comment: You could modify your mapping type and include the [`null_value` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html) in your `class_field` mapping so as to give a non-null value to that field at indexing time in case the document either doesn't contain it or has a null value. You'll need to reindex your data after changing this setting, though.

Comment: We don't wan't to modify mapping as that will mean we will have to add some logic to remove value set in null_value property. Is there some way we can do using an Aggregation query

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't see any... If you can't/won't upgrade and don't want to modify the mapping, no aggregations can help if you have missing terms.

Comment: But maybe you have misunderstood the `null_value` setting. The source of your document will not be modified at all, so you don't have to modify the logic to remove that value. The `null_value` will only be indexed so that you can find that document and aggregate on that field.

Comment: Thanks Val for the clarification. I have added null_value in the mapping and have reindex the data. Still getting back an empty bucket. Is there anything else I need to do

Comment: Have you been able to try it?

Comment: I can see null_value in the mapping and the actual document is having NULL but still get back empty bucket

Comment: Have you reindexed your data after changing the mapping? Can you share your field mapping?

Comment: Updated Post with Field Mapping

Comment: But you're are probably aggregating on the `raw` sub-field, aren't you? If that's the case, you need to move the `null_value` setting to the `raw` sub-field.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks Val for the help...It works now I have a key with the null_value...Awesome :)

Comment: Awesome!! Glad to help!

Comment: Val please let me know where I can accept the answer. Will be glad to do so.